# salesforce create a custom field partner api

Tags: java, wsdl, salesforce

i want to create custom field  in salesforce lead table by using salseforce partner/metadata API in java ,
example  want to add a custom field " add_description " in lead table by using salesforce
partner/metadata API in java ,
please help me ,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the Metadata API by using a CustomField specification, [as described here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/customfield.htm#kanchor114).

However I must question the rationale for doing this.  A more common way of adding a custom field in Salesforce.com would be to make the custom field in a development org and then to add that custom field to a Salesforce.com Package.  When users install this package to their orgs, they get this custom field, and during that installation they have the ability to choose which profiles get to see this field and what page layouts the field is exposed on.  This is generally a wiser way to disseminate your custom fields.